# What is the best way to find all the old files in a particular directory recursively in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, recursion, find, file-management

Currently I am using **find** command to find all the old files ( n days old ) matching a specific template in a particular directory recursively .

But this directory contains hundreds of subdirectories and each one again contains few more sub directories . Due to this **find** command is taking a lot of time to complete . Is there any better approach to achieve the same results .

Comment: find <base_path> -type f -name "<template>" -mtime +n

Comment: This question may have more replies in http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I could not find an answer there too :( . I will try posting the same .

Comment: Are there directories in which you do not need to find files and that you can identify in some way (e.g. by name)?

Comment: You need a faster filesystem; this is I/O-bound.  If you didn't need the age, you could use [locate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix)), which caches this information.  If you do this regularly, perhaps you want to regularly cache the data: run your find command in a cron job and dump the results to disk, then query that dump file when you want faster results.  Just don't forget that the "n days old" is relative to the last update to that dump.